# Access: Execute Code when a value in dropdown is selected

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a subform, which consists of a table.

In this table, one columns values are a dropdown field (with 3 types to choose from: `Var1`, `Var2`, `Var3`).

If a user now selects a value from this dropdown I want to execute a specific VBA code in the background.

For my understanding, that means I have to set up an event like "run code module xy if dropdown value changes".

I am a beginner and have no idea how to implement that. Hopefully you are able to help.

Thanks so much in advance!

My Code:

```
Private Sub runMacro()
    ''MyCodeHere
End Sub
```

My form with the table as a subform. You can select 3 different values for "solution". If one is selected, I want to run VBA code:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to open the form, which contains the Combo Box (the Drop Down) control, in **Design View**.

Then select this Combo Box control and open the **Property Sheet** if not already shown (you can swap its visibility with the key `F4`).

In the Property Sheet select the tab named **Event** and click into the event **After Update**.

Using the `...`-button you can select the **Code Builder** to open the VBE.

It already prepared the event handler for you, where you now can place your code.

Comment: Hi, but actually it isnt a combo box in a form. It is a field in a table which gets loaded as a subform in the form. So I cant see where I can create an event for a normal table field dropdown. .. ?

Comment: To be able to use control events of a combo box it must be a combo box control on a form. So you would have to create a new form based on that table with all necessary bound controls on it and place this form in the sub form control instead the table itself. Then you can go on using the event of the combo box as I described before.